# Direct Cpu Threads or OpenCL

Tags: multithreading, opencl, cpu

I have search the various questions (and web) but did not find any satisfactory answer.

I am curious about whether to use threads to directly load the cores of the CPU or use an OpenCL implementation. Is OpenCl just there to make multi processors/cores just more portable, meaning porting the code to either GPU or CPU or is OpenCL faster and more efficient? I am aware that GPU's have more processing units but that is not the question. Is it indirect multi threading in code or using OpneCL?

Sorry I have another question...

If the IGP shares PCI lines with the Descrete Graphics Card and its drivers can not be loaded under Windows 7, I have to assume that it will not be available, even if you want to use the processing cores of the integrated GPU only. Is this correct or is there a way to access the IGP without drivers.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As @Yann Vernier point out in the comment section, I haven't be strict enough with the terms I used. So in this post I use the term thread as a synonym of workitem. I'm not refering to the CPU threads.

I can’t really compare OCL with any other technologies that will allow using the different cores of a CPU as I only used OCL so far. 
However I might bring some input about OCL especially that I don’t really agree with ScottD. 
First of all, even though an OCL kernel developed to run on a GPU will run as well on a CPU it doesn’t mean that it’ll be efficient. The reason is simply that **OCL doesn’t work the same way on CPU and GPU**.  To have a good understanding of how it differs, see the chap 6 of [“heterogeneous computing with opencl”](http://books.google.be/books?hl=en&lr=&id=yyI8jfvi9-8C&oi=fnd&pg=PP2&dq=heterogeneous%20computing%20with%20opencl&ots=pELXTW0Hef&sig=iBRkrGH4X8dzlQlKX25MeWph1DI). 
To summary, while the GPU will launch a bunch of threads within a given workgroup at the same time, the CPU will execute on a core one thread after another within the same workgroup. See as well the point 3.4 of [the standard](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf) about the two different types of programming models supported by OCL. This can explain why an OCL kernel could be less efficient on a CPU than a “classic” code:  because it was design for a GPU. 
Whether a developer will target the CPU or the GPU is not a problem of “serious work” but is simply dependent of the type of programming model that suits best your need. Also, the fact that OCL support CPU as well is nice since it can degrade gracefully on computer not equipped with a proper GPU (though it must be hard to find such computer).
Regarding the AMD platform I’ve noticed some problem with the CPU as well on a laptop with an ATI. I observed low performance on some of my code and crashes as well. But the reason was due to the fact that the processor was an Intel.  The AMD platform will declare to have a CPU device available even if it is an Intel CPU. However it won’t be able to use it as efficiently as it should. When I run the exact same code targeting the CPU but after installing (and using) the Intel platform all the issues were gone. That’s another possible reason for poor performance.
Regarding the iGPU, it does not share PCIe lines, it is on the CPU die (at least of Intel) and yes you need the driver to use it. I assume that you tried to install the driver and got a message like” your computer does not meet the minimum requirement…” or something similar. I guess it depends on the computer, but in my case, I have a desktop equipped with a NVIDIA and an i7 CPU (it has an HD4000 GPU).  In order to use the iGPU I had first to enable it in the BIOS, which allowed me to install the driver. Of Course only one of the two GPU is used by the display at a time (depending on the BIOS setting), but **I can access both with OCL.**

Comment: A CPU running OpenCL kernels does not necessarily stick to one CL workitem per thread; it may use vector operations which are harder to access with the normal compiler, and possibly not present on each machine you run on. It won't do it on as massive a scale as a GPU, but it's certainly different from plain C or OpenMP.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Actually I was using thread as a synonym of workitem (Coming from the fact that NVIDIA uses the term thread for CUDA). I will edit my comment.

Answer (score 1):

In recent experiments using the Intel opencl tools we experienced that the opencl performance was very similar to CUDA and intrincics based AVX code on gcc and icc -- way better than earlier experiments (some years ago) where we saw opencl perform worse.